# Same code but two version of documents

Tags: html, css

I have a little problem between the url document and the print document. I don't know how to describe those documents, but you have to run the program to see the difference because I have inserted  `<script>window.print()</script>` in the `.html` file. My problem is located when I want to print the document. The print document didn't show up the table forms and the colours to compare with the url document. Could anyone be able to tell me what I have to do to fix this problem?

Here is my `mystyle.css` file

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
tr, th, td {
    border: solid 1px #fff
}
td {
    width: 50px;
    padding: 15px
}
th {
    background: #006599;
    color: #fff
}
table.inner tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #c7d4e5
}
table.inner tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #E5E5E5
}
h1 {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 0.3em 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #777;
}
h2 {
    color: #999;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding-top: 0.4em;
}
address {
    padding: 0.8em;
    font-size: 0.9em;
}
page {
    background: white;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
}
page[size="A4"] {
    width: 21cm;
    height: 29.7cm;
}
page[size="A4"][layout="portrait"] {
    width: 29.7cm;
    height: 21cm;
}
page[size="A3"] {
    width: 29.7cm;
    height: 42cm;
}
page[size="A3"][layout="portrait"] {
    width: 42cm;
    height: 29.7cm;
}
page[size="A5"] {
    width: 14.8cm;
    height: 21cm;
}
page[size="A5"][layout="portrait"] {
    width: 21cm;
    height: 14.8cm;
}
.header, .content {
    padding-right: 30%;
}
.center {
    text-align: center;
}
.border {
    border: 1px solid #777;
}
.border td, .border th {
    border: 1px solid #777;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td, table th {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 4px 8px;
}
@media print {
    body, page {
        margin: 0;
    }
    .djDebug {
        display: none;
    }
}
@media screen {
    html {
        background: #999;
    }
    body {
        margin: 20px 30%;
        padding-top: 3em;
        padding-left: 3em;
    }
}
```

Here is my `.html` file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <!--put all your javascript library or style here-->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../../loanwolf/static/loanwolf/css/mystyle.css">

    <script>
    window.print()
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    {% load i18n %}
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <center>
                    <h1>Test - {% trans "Customer profile" %}</h1>
                    <center></center>
                </center>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{% trans "Date" %}</td>
            <td>{% now "jS F Y" %}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{% trans "Customer id" %}</td>
            <td>{{ customerprofile.amortizing_table_context.customer_code}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table class='inner'>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2">
                            <h2>{% trans "General informations" %}</h2>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "First name" %}</td>
                        <td class="col-md-9">{{ customerprofile.amortizing_table_context.first_name}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Last name" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.amortizing_table_context.last_name}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Email" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.email}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Language" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.language }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Primary phone" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.phone_1 }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Secondary phone" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.phone_2 }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Fax" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.fax }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Social Security number (SSN)" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.ssn }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Birth date" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.birth_date }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Principal address" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.address }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Secondary address" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.address_line2}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "City" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.city }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "State" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.state }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Zip code" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.zip_code }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>
                <table class='inner'>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2">
                            <h2>{% trans "Financial" %}</h2>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Income source" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.financialprofile.income_source }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Bank" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.financialprofile.bank }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Bank transit" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.financialprofile.bank_transit }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Bank account" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.financialprofile.bank_account }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Monthly pay amount" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.financialprofile.pay_amount }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Pay frequency" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.financialprofile.pay_frequency }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "First pay date" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.financialprofile.first_pay_date }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Second pay date" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.financialprofile.second_pay_date }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Monthly micro loan amount" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.financialprofile.micro_loan_monthly_amount }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Account balance on pay day" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.financialprofile.bank_account_balance_on_pay_day }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Bankruptcy" %}</td>
                        <td>{% if customerprofile.financialprofile.had_bankruptcy %} {{ "Yes" }}{% else %}{{ "No" }} {% endif %}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Consumer proposal" %}</td>
                        <td>{% if customerprofile.financialprofile.had_consumer_proposal %} {{ "Yes" }}{% else %}{{ "No" }} {% endif %}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table class='inner'>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2">
                            <h2>{% trans "Employer" %}</h2>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Company name" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.employerprofile.company_name }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Job title" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.employerprofile.job_title }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Date hired" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.employerprofile.date_hired }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Supervisor name" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.employerprofile.supervisor_name }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Phone" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.employerprofile.phone }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Phone extension" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.employerprofile.phone_extension }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Address" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.employerprofile.address }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Secondary address" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.employerprofile.address_line2 }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "City" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.employerprofile.city }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "State" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.employerprofile.state }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Zip code" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.employerprofile.zip_code }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>
                <table class='inner'>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2">
                            <h2>{% trans "References" %}</h2>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Reference 1 - Fullname" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.referencesprofile.ref1_fullname }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Reference 1 - Phone" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.referencesprofile.ref1_phone }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Reference 1 - Link" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.referencesprofile.ref1_link }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Reference 2 - Fullname" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.referencesprofile.ref2_fullname }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Reference 2 - Phone" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.referencesprofile.ref2_phone }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Reference 2 - Link" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.referencesprofile.ref2_link }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: `<script>
    window.print()
   </script>`
put this just above `</body>`

Comment: @HariLamichhane Sorry, but it didn't work so far.

Comment: The user needs to choose Background in the print options dialog. There is no way you the programmer can control this. You could have googled for "background browser print" and found something right away.